# Install package from ppa with setup.py file

Tags: python, packaging

I am writing a python program that I want to upload to a ppa so other people can install it on their machine. Right now I have a setup.py-file that copies the files to their place and installs the dependencies, if not already done. My point is: To install, the setup.py-file has to be executed. Is this done by typing the "sudo apt-get install 'package-name'"? Or do I need a make, controll, install file like debian for this to work?

Right now if I wanna install, I type 'sudo python3 setup.py install'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to "package" your Python program into the Debian packaging format.

Packaging for Debian is pretty complex, but here are some pointers to get you started:

How to package a Python application:

https://wiki.debian.org/Python/Packaging

The Debian new package  maintainer's guide (best starting point to grasp all the concepts):
https://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/index.en.html

Finally the big reference, the Debian policy manual:

https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-scope.html